# Which Logging timestamp format?

Tags: json, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

To a me a log containing a timestamp field expressed as a string like "2021-05-12T09:49:57+08:00" is far easier to understand than say a long milliseconds since epoch, e.g. "1620784365000".

So I don't understand some documentation like [Cloudwatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_AnalyzeLogData-discoverable-fields.html) which describes its [InputLogEvent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_InputLogEvent.html) of a type Long **The time the event occurred, expressed as the number of milliseconds after Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.**

However when I study the raw Cloudwatch log, it appears to be a string:

[image]

So I am a little confused, which is it? A string or a long and where is this documented?

Answer (score 0):

Use a long as it is documented.

When you study the raw Cloudwatch log, the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_AnalyzeLogData-discoverable-fields.html mentions that

> For every log sent to CloudWatch Logs, five system fields are
> automatically generated:

and

> @timestamp contains the event timestamp contained in the log event's
> timestamp field. This is equivalent to the timestamp field in
> InputLogevent.

Therefore, it's very likely that the raw Cloudwatch log you studied is not the original event log, they are equivalent but might not be exactly the same. The raw Cloudwatch log you studied may have its original data parsed and converted during the automatically generated process for ease of understanding.

Comment: Ah, I found the raw logs now https://s.natalian.org/2021-05-17/1621259278_1918x1078.png

Comment: I'm confused, so the log you screenshot in the question is not the raw logs?